# PayPal Micropayments for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I've discovered that PayPal has quite an attractive micropayment system in comparison to other services.  According to [this](https://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_micropayments.html) they have a micropayment range from >$0 to

Further, other services such as Recurly and Chargify, I am discovering upon very close scrutiny, are cost prohibitive for micropayment models.  Please do correct me if I'm wrong as I had my finger on the trigger for Recurly until I had this revelation from reviewing more closely the Amazon FPS & PaPal micropayment transaction fee structure.

Given this new understanding, again, please do correct me if I'm wrong, I am taking an approach that I *must* go with an option more akin to SaaS Kit for Rails (which doesn't seem to support this method of PayPal transactions for credit cards) or some other sort of payment mechanism to handle the monthly subscription transactions.

Does anyone have a solution that works for your situation if similar?  Have you heard or seen a solution that fits into this model and takes out having to build the transaction system?  Or am I better off biting the bullet and just building it atop PayPal's infrastructure and / or API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell you should be able to use [Active Merchant](http://www.activemerchant.org/) for this.

For recurring payments, [here](http://blog.matthodan.com/how-to-add-support-for-paypal-website-payment) is a blog post I referred to a ton when I was originally setting up paypal transactions with active merchant. It details the process of setting up recurring payments with paypal and using a paypal developer account.

Comment: As far as I can tell this patch MAY take care of the recurring payments issue as it was just made a few weeks ago: http://bit.ly/qkyym9  -- From your experience and from a review of this patch, can you tell if that will obviate the need of the blog post to which you referred?

Comment: The blog post was just a reference, I found it useful when I was first trying to use active merchant but there are tons of other tutorials out there (including the railscasts mentioned by eveevans). After glancing at the patch code it does look like it causes the bit of the blog dealing with recurring payments to be obsolete, although I don't fully understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try Active Merchant, you can see it uses and examples of its implementation with paypal here : 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/144-active-merchant-basics and 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/145-integrating-active-merchant